# Flex 4.1 and OSMF 1.5 - does it work?

Tags: eclipse, flash, apache-flex, builder, osmf

The Flex 4.1 SDK ships with OSMF 1.0. For new features, OSMF can be updated.

Adding the updated **osmf.swc** to a Flex 4.1 project, I get error messages as soon as I add an OSMF component in my application (VideoDisplay in the sceenshot):

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHk6.png

[OSMF 1.5 download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osmf.adobe/files/)

According to the documentation, **OSMF 1.5** should work with the **Flex 4.1** SDK.
Unfortunately, I have to stick to Flex 4.1 because Flash 10.1 needs to be supported (Flex 4.5 needs Flash 10.2)
When I change the SDK to version 4.5, the error messages disappears and it compiles as expected.

--> Is the documentation wrong about supporting Flex 4.1 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

1. Make sure you don't have two versions of OSMF in the library path.  Since you added the new one, make sure you removed the old one.  Sometimes it is the simple things.
2. Look for a version of OSMF that is explicitly compiled against the Flex 4.1 framework.  Sometimes errors such as this relate to a version mismatch between the SWC and the version of the SDK you are using in your main project.  Since the OSMF source should be available, you could download it and compile it against the Flex 4.1 SDK if a pre-compiled version is not available.  I suspect that will make these errors go away.

Answer (score 0):

[NetGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html) is only available for Flash Player 10.1 and above.  When you specify a Flex project in Flash Builder, it tries to use the lowest Flash Player requirement.  Just need to change it to 10.1 in the project properties and it should work.

Comment: You're right about NetGroup. Unfortunately, it solves only 2 of 3 errors. Still not working with explicit 10.1: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: DimensionEvent."

Comment: The hell is DimensionEvent? that's not part of Flash.

Comment: Hello again J_A_X, how do you set the minimum flash player required to 10.1 in FB ? I just can't seem to see this option